# google apps script gadget to create dynamic links

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script Gadget for my google sites page. The gadget should display a list of 3 URLs to links within the site based on a search string.

e.g. a site contains many articles on dogs. A user opens up an article on "how to train your dog". At the bottom of the page would be the gadget listing 3 other articles with similar key words.

```
//global constants
var SEARCH_KEY = "train your dog"

// Script-as-app template.
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var mySite = SitesApp.getSite('mysite.com','mysite');

  var advancedArgs = {max:"3"};
  var page = mySite.search(SEARCH_KEY, advancedArgs);

  for (i = 0; i < page.length;i++)
  {
    app.add(app.createHTML('<a href=\"' + page[i].getUrl() + '\">' + page[i].getTitle() + '</a>'));
    app.create
  }

  return app;
}
```

However, the createHTML function only seems to accept basic formatting such as bold, itallic. Does anyone have any ideas on how to create a list of URLs within a gadget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special widget for this purpose : [createAnchor("a link", "www.google.com");](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_anchor)

in which you can define the shown string and the link...

EDIT : for info, here is a list of allowed HTML tags in UiApp HTML widget :([release note](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/release_notes) March 7, 2012)

*Added the ability to include a limited set of HTML tags when working with UiApp widgets, in response to this issue. Here is the list of HTML tags that are permitted: B, BLOCKQUOTE, BODY, BR, CENTER, CAPTION, CITE, CODE, DIV, EM, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, HR, I, LABEL, LEGEND, LI, OL, P, SPAN, STRONG, SUB, SUP, TABLE, TBODY, TD, THEAD, TITLE, TR, TT, UL*

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it working with createAnchor("text","url")